# Split array into sub arrays and replace character

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need to split an array into several sub arrays and replace a certain character.

First I run a function to count the number of duplicates in the array. Then I build a new array with the values and the number of instances of the value.

Code:

```
    angular.forEach($scope.financial, function(data) {
        counts[data] = (counts[data] || 0)+1; 
    })
```

Result:

```
[4, {25: 4}, 5, {25: 1}, 3, {10: 1}, 4, {10: 1}]
```

What I am looking for is to split the array into several sub arrays and replace the colon with a comma.

Like this:

```
[[4,25,4],[5,25,1],[3,10,1],[4,10,1]]
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you show us the initial contents of `$scope.financial`?

Comment: The initial content is like this: `[[4,25],[5,25],[3,10],[4,10]]`

Comment: Why not use regular objects with property names instead? Sure beats having to read documentation to know what different indices mean...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That can be done with a simple loop. But, some checks for the integrity of the data would be advised if you can't guarantee the format of the input.

```js
function getKey(o) {
  for (var prop in o) {
    if (o.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
      return prop;
    }
  }
}

var data = [4, {25: 4}, 5, {25: 1}, 3, {10: 1}, 4, {10: 1}];
var i = 0;
var output = [];
var key;

for (i = 0; i < data.length; i += 2) {
  key = getKey(data[i + 1]);
  output.push([data[i], parseInt(key, 10), data[i + 1][key]]);
}

//Print the output
console.log(output);

var el = document.createElement('div');
el.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(output);
document.body.appendChild(el);
```

Answer (score 1):

The below mentioned converter function will accept the reponseArray of type `[4, {25: 4}, 5, {25: 1}, 3, {10: 1}, 4, {10: 1}]` and converts into subarray `[[4,25,4],[5,25,1],[3,10,1],[4,10,1]]`

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s61hjp5s/)

```
function converter(responseArray) {
    var mainArray=[], subArray;
    for (var i = 0; i < responseArray.length; i++) { 
        if(i%2 == 0) {
         subArray= [];
         subArray.push(responseArray[i]);
        } else {
             var obj = responseArray[i];
             for(var key in obj) {
                subArray.push(key * 1);
                subArray.push(obj[key] * 1);
             }
             mainArray.push(subArray);
        }
    }
    console.log(mainArray);
    return mainArray;
}
```